# How can i save Images in PhotoAlbem if not available from my Native application?

Tags: ios4, photolibrary

My Application is like WALLPAPER PREVIEW.i am using images from default photo library so how can i store images in Photo library from my native application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be helpfull

[save images to photo library, but sometimes can not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578108/save-images-to-photo-library-but-sometimes-can-not-work-correctly)